Connect to vpn from the terminal using Cisco AnyConnect in 2024
I was using "/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn" to connect to vpn's from the terminal. However, today this kept hanging and I tried the GUI. There it downloaded an update before connecting and then finally successfully connected. However, it appears that after the (forced) update there is no executable such as "/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn" at all anymore. In fact there is no "/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/" at all anymore.
Is it still possible to connect through the command line or has that support been removed in a recent update?

Ubuntu 24.04

This is software that you (or your company) is paying for, right? Raise a support ticket

In the new version which is called secureclient the default path is:
/opt/cisco/secureclient/bin

